# R saving plots into memory (Java compatible)

Tags: java, r, performance, png, cairo

Is there a faster way to save plots directly to byte[] or base64 or anything that Java can read easily ... looking for **~1ms or less**

This is what i have working so far, but it's too slow...

```
# PNG raw 50ms
library(Cairo)
library(png)
Cairo(filename="test",width=500,height=500)
plot(cars)
i  = Cairo:::.image(dev.cur())
r = Cairo:::.ptr.to.raw(i$ref, 0, i$width * i$height * 4)
dim(r) = c(4, i$width, i$height)
r[c(1,3),,] = r[c(3,1),,]
p <- writePNG(r, raw())

# XML 4ms
library(svglite)
x <- xmlSVG({ plot(cars) })
```

So far using BufferedImage i get from R Cairo sample.

Goal: Getting plots as image into java, bridge is JRI (rJava)

Comment: If you can explain what you are trying to do with the plot in java and how many points are in the data, it will be easier for others to answer. I am left wondering what formats might work for your use case besides rendering a png and just how much data you are looking at. The png in your code is fairly low resolution which makes me think it doesn't need to contain a lot of data.

Comment: Goal: Getting plots as image into java, could be byte buffer, or base64, anything i can draw then with JavaFX - bridge is JRI (rJava)

Comment: i'd be interested to know if you ever improved on this. I am interested in going the other way Java->R